# Add Bundle in Cart with Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api

Tags: magento, bundle, cart

I need to insert a **bundle** in my shopping cart using the API for Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api,

```
function add($quoteId, $productsData, $store = null)
```

The simple product can perfectly, but I have problems with the bundle.

there are probably errors in the creation of the $productsData?

```
$productsData = array ('product_id' => $productId,
'qty' => $qty);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry my friend but our problem is that we need to insert a bundle in a cart, but we don't use the model "checkout/cart", but "checkout/cart_product_api" because we'll be able to add a bundle in a defined quote_id.

this is the function:

```
$params = array(
        'product_id' => $productId,
        'related_product' => null,
        'bundle_option' => array(
                57 => array(0 => 37,
                        1 => 38
                ),
        'bundle_qty' => 1));

Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_product_api')->add($cartId, $params, $store_id['eshop_id']);
```